# C calculator program doesnt work properly

Tags: c, calculator

I wrote a calculator program in C but it doesnt work as intended.
P is an acumulator that stores the current number, its like a memory of calculator.
if you want to perform an operation, like +, you do P  + , it doesnt matter if + or numbers are on different lines, blank spaces dont count. My code works for P 20 + 20 as intended. If you want to get the result you type =. So if You input P 20 + 20 = , the result should be 40. For P 20 + 20 + 20 the result should be 60, however, in my program its still 40. I will attach photos of my inputs and the expected inputs.

[image: Left input and output is wrong and right is correct input and output]

[image: Left input and output is wrong and right is correct input and output]

Code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_error_message(char *message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
}


bool calculate(void)
{
    int ch;
    int akumulator = 0;
    int number = 0;
    char operation = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == ' ') {
            continue;
        }

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'P':
                operation = 1;
                akumulator = 0;
                break;
            case '+':
                number = 0;
                operation = 2;
                break;

            default:
                ;
        }

        if (operation == 1)
        {
            if (isdigit(ch)){
                akumulator = (akumulator *  10) + (ch - '0');
            }
        }

        if (operation == 2)
        {
            if (isdigit(ch)){
                number = (number *  10) + (ch - '0');
            } else{
                akumulator = akumulator + number;
            }
        }

        if ((operation == 0) && isdigit(ch))
        {
            print_error_message("Syntax error");
            return false;
        }

        if (operation != 0)
        {
            if (ch == '=' || ch == ';' || ch == '+')
            {
                printf("# %d", akumulator);
                putchar('\n');
            }
            if (ch == EOF)
            {
                printf("# %d", akumulator);
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }

        if (ch == '=')
        {
            printf("# %d", akumulator);
            putchar('\n');
        }

    }
    print_error_message("SYNTAX ERROR");

    return false;
}


int main(void)
{
    if (!calculate()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: in `case '+'`, you reset number to zero, but you don't increment the accumulator.

Comment: (or, rather, you are incrementing the accumulator too late in the code: you need to do it before you reset to zero)

Answer (score 1):

Reset the number only after incrementing it in the accumulator. See the below code (commented the modified parts):

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == ' ') {
        continue;
    }

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'P':
            operation = 1;
            akumulator = 0;
            break;
        case '+':
            //removed the number reset
            operation = 2;
            break;

        default:
            ;
    }

    if (operation == 1)
    {
        if (isdigit(ch)){
            akumulator = (akumulator *  10) + (ch - '0');
        }
    }

    if (operation == 2)
    {
        if (isdigit(ch)){
            number = (number *  10) + (ch - '0');
        } else{
            akumulator = akumulator + number;
            number = 0; // number is resetted here!
        }
    }

    if ((operation == 0) && isdigit(ch))
    {
        print_error_message("Syntax error");
        return false;
    }

    if (operation != 0)
    {
        if (ch == '=' || ch == ';' || ch == '+')
        {
            printf("# %d", akumulator);
            putchar('\n');
        }
        if (ch == EOF)
        {
            printf("# %d", akumulator);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    if (ch == '=')
    {
        printf("# %d", akumulator);
        putchar('\n');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem I have now is that inputs and outputs differ a second time you type =. Example: https://imgur.com/cczQiyC ;#40 is twice in my output and should only be once as the right correct output

Comment: @BLINAK It is because you are printing the accumulator twice when `ch == =`. If you put `printf("1st position # %d", akumulator);` inside  `if (ch == '=' || ch == ';' || ch == '+')` and  `printf("2nd position# %d", akumulator);` inside `if (ch == '=')` then you will see from where you are getting two results. Quick fix: Remove the second if `(ch == '=')`to get a single result.

Comment: But that solution removes the double # I get if I use = for the first time. Look at the screenshot link above. For the first time I type = I want it to be # 40 #40, but for the second time I want it only once, exactly like it is in the screenshot. So if I do =, it prints #40 #40, I do = again, it prints #40, I then do + 20 = for example, I want it again to be double, in this case, #60 #60 and then if I do = again, its only once: #60

Comment: @BLINAK If I understood correctly, then the accumulator shouldnt be printed if there is no change in accumulator value.  So, it is easy to solve. You just need to remember the previous value and compare it.